# Nested props in styled-components giving Typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm trying to call a prop within a styled-component, but it's giving me an error :

```
[ts] Property 'color' does not exist on type 'ThemeProps<any>'.
```

Here's the code with the issue:

```
  const ButtonContainer = styled.button`
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: ${theme.s2};
  border: 2px solid ${props => props.color};
  background: ${props => props.color};
  color: ${theme.textDark};

  ${(props: { secondary?: boolean }) =>
    props.secondary &&
    css`
      background: none;
      color: ${props => props.color};
      }
    `}
`;
```

With the error showing on the last instance of props.color.

Any ideas how to correctly type this instance? I assume it's something to

```
${(props: { secondary?: boolean })
```

Typescript version 3.3.3333 and styled-components 4.1.3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
color: ${(props: {color: string }) => props.color};
```

Hope this helps. :)